# disadvantage of attack in php mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

i have the following code below its working but someone says its prone to sql injection attack how can i prevent it ? the code below actually inserts data into table messages and after inserting it echo a string message inserted.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
$f = date('d-m-Y');
$e = date("h:i:sa");
$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$sql="insert into messages values($f,$e,$name,$phone,$email,$message,$replymail,$replyphone)";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
if($result === TRUE)
{
echo"Message Inserted";
}
```

It will be helpful if you can help

Comment: What is $conn, is it a PDO object? Anyway, google for "prepared statements"

Comment: no its just simple mysql connect

Comment: Hi, my name is [`Robert'); DROP TABLE messages;--`](http://bobby-tables.com/) can I register in your app?

Comment: Won't work in PHP @apokryfos because multiple SQL statements will trigger a error in PHP's MySQLi and PDO functions. Only the function mysqli_multi_query() can execute multiple SQl statements.

Comment: @RaymondNijland it's meant to be a joke, but people with punctuation in their names (and yes they exist) won't be able to register on apps that use the above code which translates to unhappy people. Injection of built-in mysql functions can also occur which is probably worse

Comment: Do try and get out of the habit of cluttering up your code with needless things like `=== true`. Many functions are designed to return values that evaluate as logically true or false so that's redundant.

Comment: Note: Try and get out of the habit of declaring SQL statements in throw-away variables that are used only once. It's a lot easier to follow code where the query is supplied directly to the function, and there's no longer a chance of messing up and sending in `$sql3` instead of the visually similar `$sql8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is bind_param statements, use prepare statements to ensure that your php mysql scripting is safe from mysql injections, also its better than using mysql_real_escape_strings() at variable as i have read somewhere they aren't as much reliable as prepare statements

```
$sql =$conn->prepare("insert into messages values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$sql->bind_param("ssssssss",$f,$e,$name,$phone,$email,$message,$replymail,$replyphone);

if($sql->execute())
{
echo"Message Inserted";
}
```